# UL inside a Div vertically centered | Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I'm new at StackOverflow (and HTML5/CSS) and this is my first post. (and I'm not speak english very well)

I'm trying to make a nav bar inside a div but I can't centered vertically. I've tried:

- vertical-align: middle;
- change the height of the content div and center the UL
- "play" with display property
- read every post I've found on internet but I can't figure out.

  .article {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color:rgba(210,246,1, 1);
  }

```html
<div class="row article">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{% static 'imagenes/logo.png' %}" alt="Stia" class="logopeque">Convenio Vigente
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{% static 'imagenes/logo.png' %}" alt="Stia" class="logopeque">Escala Salarial vigente
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{% static 'imagenes/logo.png' %}" alt="Stia" class="logopeque">Escalas Salariales Anteriores
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <section>
      <p class="centrarp">
        <h3>Convenio 244/94</h3>
        <h5 class="justificar">TRABAJADORES COMPRENDIDOS - ENUNCIACION DE ACTIVIDADES</h5>
        <p class="justificar centrarp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSS7W.png)

Comment: It's not clear what element you want to center in what element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't want this on every `.row.article` on your website, I added a custom class: `.vCenter`.

```css
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .row.article.vCenter {
    display: flex;
  }
  .row.article.vCenter>.col-lg-3 .nav-pills {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row article vCenter">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{% static 'imagenes/logo.png' %}" alt="Stia" class="logopeque">Convenio Vigente
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{% static 'imagenes/logo.png' %}" alt="Stia" class="logopeque">Escala Salarial vigente
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="{% static 'imagenes/logo.png' %}" alt="Stia" class="logopeque">Escalas Salariales Anteriores
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <section>
      <p class="centrarp">
        <h3>Convenio 244/94</h3>
        <h5 class="justificar">TRABAJADORES COMPRENDIDOS - ENUNCIACION DE ACTIVIDADES</h5>
        <p class="justificar centrarp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you prefer them more "spaced", you could try `space-around` or even `space-between` instead of `center` for `justify-content`.

And don't forget to parse your final CSS through [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) before deploying.